# How do I automatically update dynamic master sheet referencing data from other sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to create a publishing schedule in Excel. I want to have master sheet A,

[image]
which collates information from all of the other child sheets B, C, D etc

[image]

to show all the articles that are being published.

These will all be in one workbook, with different teams updating their individual child sheet separately. Then the overall schedule can be viewed on master sheet A.

All the sheets will have the same headings (Day of the week, Date, Type, Description, Contact, Notes). The problem I'm having with this is how to pull the information from the child sheets in such a way that the master sheet will automatically add rows of information, under the correct day of week & date.

[image]

So far I have only been able to link sheets by having data input into the same cell across the sheets, which is not useful to me in this case. It needs to dynamically add the data to the right date.

I wondered about using UserForm but not sure if I would just be overcomplicating things. Maybe this will need a macro code? Advice appreciated.

Comment: Please supply some sample data together with an example of what you want and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Probably lots of ways to solve. My approach would be to **use query in Excel** to **consolidate the subsidiary worksheet data** into a common worksheet. Then I'd use a **pivot table to organize, filter and present** the information. Use **slicers** and other controls to make the "publication master" a more user friendly "dashboard".